# Campaign Tacking with Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, campaign-monitor, google-analytics-campaign-builder

I have integrated firebase analytics into my android project but I am not able to understand how to manage campaign tracking with firebase analytics.
Right no we are seeing only 3 parameter

1. direct
2. Not set
3. google-play

but our promotion is going on at Facebook, Google, Whatsapp etc sites, unfortunately, we are not able to track how many installs from which campaign.
As I know we can track by google Campaign Measurement but it needs google analytics and I don't want to add Google analytics in my project again.
If anyone has a better solution for this problem kindly propose to me.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Have you found an answer?

Answer (score 2):

In order to track installs coming from google adwords you have to connect your adwords account to your firebase project by following the steps listed in here :

https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6333536?co=ADWORDS.IsAWNCustomer%3Dfalse&hl=en

Once you do so a new 4th source would start appearing under the name "google" this will report back on installs coming specifically from your Adwords account campaigns connected to firebase.

Unfortunately for Facebook and Whatsapp you have to either use deep_links when available but you cannot track from firebase directly.

I hope this answer helps.

Good luck !

Comment: Thank you answer.

Comment: Once you did that, you can also enable the Firebase BigQuery Export and see the raw values for deep_links there. You can parse the values and set the correct source (Whatsapp, Facebook, etc.) over there. That's how we do it at Rakam, see https://rakam.io/solution/firebase.